# How to import playframework sources into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, playframework

After cloning playframework from [github](http://www.github.com/playframework/play) and importing java sources into eclipse there are a lot of build errors shown.

Running the goals from ant file in eclipse works fine as well as building from cli directly.

How can i resolve these errors in eclipse?

I took the following steps to import play into eclipse:

- new -> other -> Java>New Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile
- select play/framework/build.xml
- checking the 'Link to the build file in the file system' checkbox
- Finish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors result from differences between eclipse internal build path
and classpath available for ant at runtime.

First Eclipse only imports rt.jar from system path. This may lead to
missing dependecies in javax.net packages (e.g.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException), which is located in jsse.jar. To fix, right
click on project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Library->
JRE System Library.

Second, play has dependencies to classes from ant runtime. To fix, right
click on project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add
Library->User Library
There you have to add a new User Library (perhaps call it ANT) and add
all ant-jars from your ant installation (/usr/share/ant/lib/ worked for
me). Then add this user library to play projects build path.

Answer (score 1):

From the Oliver's answer, I had also to add the jce.jar lib in my classpath.

It comes from the $JDK/jre/lib directory.